# Add files to Xcode project through command line ? Use of project.pbxproj file in Xcode?

Tags: python, xcode

I was trying to add a plist file to a xcode project through command line, some of the blogs suggested to edit the `project.pbxproj` file. I searched about the `project.pbxproj` file but was not able to get much information about it. Can anyone let me know what is use of the `project.pbxproj` file in xcode? How does one add entries to it?

I am using [this repo](https://github.com/kronenthaler/mod-pbxproj) to work with it.

the script that I wrote is as follows:

```
import sys
import os
from mod_pbxproj import XcodeProject


def addPlistInProject(corodova_proj_name, xcode_proj_name, plist_file_name):
    print "Cordova project name : " + corodova_proj_name
    present_directory = os.getcwd()
    path_to_xcode_proj = present_directory + '/' + corodova_proj_name + '/platforms/ios/' + xcode_proj_name + '.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'
    print "Xcode Project Path : " + path_to_xcode_proj
    project = XcodeProject.Load(path_to_xcode_proj)
    project.get_or_create_group('new group')
    project.add_file(plist_file_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    corodova_proj_name = sys.argv[1]
    xcode_proj_name = sys.argv[2]
    plist_file_name = sys.argv[3]
    print "Xcode Project Name = : " + xcode_proj_name
    print "Plist File Path = : " + plist_file_name
    addPlistInProject(corodova_proj_name, xcode_proj_name, plist_file_name)
```

I will be invoking the script as:

```
python myscript.py hello HelloWorld manisha-rules_camdo.plist
```

`myscript.py` is the script I wrote, `hello` is the existing cordova project and `HelloWorld` is the Xcode project created by using `cordova platform add iOS`.

The command Sequence I will be following will be as follows:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cordova platform add iOS
py myscript.py hello HelloWorld manisha-rules_camdo.plist
```

Where `hello` is the name of cordova project and `HelloWorld` name of iOS target.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a Ruby API from Cocoapods for editing Xcode projects. It also have an active community of developers:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj

Answer (score 8):

Another great option, especially for Cordova projects, is to use the XCODE node module: [node-xcode](https://github.com/alunny/node-xcode);  you can easily add it via NPM.

Once in place, you can create an **after_prepare** hook to modify the pbxproj, injecting custom source files, additional frameworks, etc, on every build.  In fact, Cordova itself leverages this module during its own build processes.

Within my solution, I first added the module via npm:

```
npm install xcode --save-dev
```

And then I created and after_prepare hook to add extra frameworks into my XCode project:

```
var xcode = require('xcode'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    rootdir = process.argv[2],
    projectPath = rootdir + '/platforms/ios/my-project/project.pbxproj',
    proj = new xcode.project(projectPath);

proj.parse(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Oh noes! XCODE project failed to parse:");
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        proj.addFramework('Fabric.framework', {customFramework:true});
        proj.addFramework('Crashlytics.framework', {customFramework:true});
        proj.addFramework('AdSupport.framework');
        proj.addFramework('FacebookSDK.framework', {customFramework:true});

        fs.writeFileSync(projectPath, proj.writeSync());
        console.log("Updated XCODE project with references to social libs!");
    }
});
```

The XCODE module is smart enough to know if the frameworks / files / etc that you are trying to add are already present, and won't try to add them again.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking to do is not the most straightforward thing. The Xcode pbxproj file format looks like XML, but I think there's quite a few proprietary / undocumented pieces to it (much like everything iOS).  As far as I can tell, Xcode doesn't have any way to add files from the command line.

I did find a Python script that you might be able to use to modify Xcode's project files, but it's a few years old and it might be out of date.

[Here is the Blog post that talks about it](https://coderwall.com/p/dhnceq) and [here is the current GitHub repo](https://github.com/kronenthaler/mod-pbxproj) (last updated five months ago, as of the date of me typing this answer).

Give this a try and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I have used your blog for it ! Have edited the question by stating exactly that I have done ! Please review if I am doing it write because I am nt getting files added into project

Comment: I am not able add file using the same script in xcode 6

Comment: darn!  It sounds like you need to open some ["issues" in Git (i.e. bug reports)](https://github.com/kronenthaler/mod-pbxproj/issues) for the author to look at.

Comment: Thanks :) it was great help.

Comment: I have mailed the author I am waiting for reply.